# Delphi 10: Problems with SizeOf(string) - Windows vs Android

Tags: android, delphi, indy10, delphi-10-seattle

I want to send TMemoStream from Android to Windows using Indy IdTCPClient and IdTCPServer.

The problem is this:

```
SizeOf(string) in Android is 4 bytes
SizeOf(string) in Windows 10 is 8 bytes
```

In android I used this code:

```
type TMyRecord = record
  x1: string;
  x2: string;
end;

var
  workRecord: TMyRecord;
  rInfo: TMemoryStream;
begin
  workRecord.x1:= 'Hello';
  workRecord.x2:= 'How are you';
  rInfo:= TMemoryStream.Create;

  try
    rInfo.Write(workRecord, SizeOf(workRecord));  //Size of workRecord is 8 bytes
    AndroidTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(workRecord, 0, False);
  finally
    rInfo.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In Windows 10 I used this code:

```
type TMyRecord = record
  x1: string;
  x2: string;
end;

type TMyRecord = record
  x1: string;
  x2: string;
end;

var
  workRecord: TMyRecord;
  rInfo: TMemoryStream;
begin
  rInfo:= TMemoryStream.Create;

  try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(rInfo, SizeOf(workRecord), False);
    rInfo.Position:= 0;
    rInfo.Read(workRecord, SizeOf(workRecord)); //Size of workRecord is 16 bytes
  finally
    rInfo.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Anyone advise me how to set up the transmission string from Android to Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(string)` is the size of a pointer. Your Windows program is clearly compiled for 64 bit and so pointers are 8 bytes wide. Your Android program targets 32 bit and pointers are 4 bytes wide.

The bigger problem is that you cannot expect to send pointers from one process to another. The pointers refer to memory in the sending program. They have no meaning in the recipient. You should probably serialize your data, for instance to JSON, and then send that. Then the recipient can deserialize upon receipt.

Comment: You're right, I did not realize that my Windows 10 running on 64-bit. Thanks.

Comment: It is not so much that your Windows 10 system is 64 bit, it matters that your **program** is 64 bit.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just badly phrased the answer.

Comment: Another problem worth mentioning is that on mobile platforms strings are zero based (first character index is 0) while on Windows they are 1 based (first character index is 1). So even if you manage to send RAW memory data of string from one platform to another you won't be getting same results. Therefore I agree with David about serializing your data before sending it between different platforms.

Comment: @SilverWarior Not really. The `string` variable always points to the first character. That is `S[1]` for 1-based strings, and `S[0]` for 0-based strings. The raw data is in the exact same place. It's just that the compiler generates different code for the `[]` operator depending on the index base.